# Crawling RSS: Scrapy returned no data

Tags: scrapy

Here's my code to crawl RSS BBC but it returned nothing.

I checked xpath interactively using "Inspect" in Chrome and it seemed OK.

```
import scrapy


class BbcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bbc"
    allowed_domains = ["feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml"]
    start_urls = ["https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml"]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_rss = response.xpath('//div[@id="item"]/ul/li')
        for rss in all_rss:
            rss_url = rss.xpath('//a/@href').extract_first()
            rss_title = rss.xpath('//a/text()').extract_first()
            rss_short_content = rss.xpath('//div/text()').extract_first()
            yield {
            "URL": rss_url,
            "Title": rss_title,
            "Short Content": rss_short_content
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response is a .txt file so you can parse it in following way:

```
import scrapy


class BbcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bbc"
    allowed_domains = ["feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml"]
    start_urls = ["https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml"]

        def parse(self, response):
            rss_url = response.xpath('//link/text()').extract()[2:]
            rss_title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[2:]
            rss_short_content = response.xpath('//description/text()').extract()
            for i in range(len(rss_url)):
                yield {
                "URL": rss_url[i],
                "Title": rss_title[i],
                "Short Content": rss_short_content[i],
                }
```

The first two URLs and titles had nothing to do with news so I dropped them.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this crawler not yielding any data, because `all_rss` list is empty. Secondly, In Scrapy you have access to only the first GET request so if you open-source code using ctrl/cmd + U, you will be unable to find `item` id. So your
`response.xpath('//div[@id="item"]/ul/li')` selector returns empty list and for loop didn't execute.

Try this

```
    for rss in response.css('item'):
        rss_url = rss.css('link::text').extract_first()
        rss_title = rss.css('title::text').extract_first()
        rss_short_content = response.css('description::text').extract_first()
```

Comment: Hi @Ikram, so how should i fix this?
I added rss_url = response.xpath('//div[@id="item"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract_first() right inside the function and not using loop but it still return None.

Comment: This will not. You are trying to get something which is not present in a page source. Try this.